# How to ignore custom tokens using curly braces in vue.js

Tags: javascript, mustache, vue.js

There is a vuejs component called my-comp with a given data that I want to iterate on its elements and print them:

```
<my-comp json-data='[{"id":1,"text":"Hello"},{"id":2,"text":"World"}]' inline-template>
    <div v-repeat="d: data">
        <div>
            {{ d.id }}
        </div>
        <div>
            {{ d.text }}
        </div>
    </div>
</my-comp>
```

And it works fine if there is no curly braces within `text` property of my `d` object but if there is, a TypeError exception will be thrown: `TypeError: res is undefined` and the only way I know to fix it, is to escape curly braces with back slash: change `{{ token }}` to `{\{ token }\}`.

Is there any more convenient way to ignore curly braces within vuejs or Am I doing something wrong?
Here is a [working code with no {{}}](http://jsfiddle.net/2czoahyL/), and here is [how {{}} breaks it](http://jsfiddle.net/dhgzou8h/) & I'm using version 0.12.16.

Comment: I'm not sure which version if Vue you're using but you can do `json-data.literal='...'` in the latest beta I believe. I'm not sure how to approach it in this version. I imagine just trying to read the attribute off the element itself could work but Vue is telling me that component is a text node (I'm guessing something related to `inline-template`.

Comment: latest stable one: v0.12.16
So I guess I should wait till the next stable version (v1.*)

Comment: I think this doesn't happen in newer versions of Vue. If you want to include literal curly brackets, have a look at [`v-pre`](https://012.vuejs.org/api/directives.html#v-pre)

Answer (score 0):

If you pass a props like you did, and you want Vue to evaluate this content,you need to bind it using: `:your-data="expression"`

I've updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/krzystof/2czoahyL/1/)

Also in your case you shouldn't do v-for in the first element of your component (you would have a [fragment instance](http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Fragment_Instance))

And you don't need to do anything in your Vue data because arrays and objects are parsed by vue when using the v-bind directive.